# Error starting Kafka kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1

Tags: apache-kafka

```
bin/zookeeper-shell.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Connecting to config/zookeeper.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: config: Name or service not known

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you. If not please let me know what didn't work. If you mark answer as accepted, then your question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the zookeeper shell you need to provide the machine on which it is running as parameter, not the properties file:

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
```

Comment: that's not what the documentation says:  bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: `zookeeper-shell.sh` and `zookeeper-server-start.sh` are completely different scripts. First one (in your original question) used to manage zookeeper instance (get data, create nodes, etc.). The second one (which you've mentioned in comment above) starts zookeeper server, as documentation says. In the question you were starting `zookeeper-shell.sh` which needs a zookeeper server running already.